# Boolean LINQ Issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a field in my database table called `IsActive` that can either be `True` or `False`. When I query the database, though, my query also returns the inactive rows:

**This is my LINQ Query:**

```
var j = from x in db.DashboardMenus 
        where x.ParentID == c.SiteMenuID && c.IsActive == true 
        orderby x.SortOrder ascending 
        select x;
```

Comment: Just a tip, you don't need `== true`, either use `c.IsActive` for `true`, or `!c.IsActive` for `false`

Answer (score 12):

You've got a typo in your query. You're using `c.IsActive` when you should be using `x.IsActive`, since that's the table object you're trying to query. Otherwise it will return all `x` objects where the ParentID and SiteMenuID match as long as `c` is active (which appears to be your problem).

```
var j = from x in db.DashboardMenus 
        where x.ParentID == c.SiteMenuID && x.IsActive
        orderby x.SortOrder ascending 
        select x;
```

In the future, you might be better served by having more descriptive (and longer) variable names (even for LINQ queries) to make better sure that you don't run into this problem again.